# Power BI Gateway on-prem server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a MSSQL server on-prem and followed the steps from [Microsofts Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem#download-and-install-the-power-bi-gateway---enterprise)
in order to install the gateway.

Than i managed the gateway via manage gateways within power bi (cloud) and the test there worked and i got the green check.

Now the question how do i get the data from the gateway into a dataset? when i try to add a new dataset there and click on data bases i only get Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, SQL Server Analysis and Spark on Azure HDInsight but now sign of my fresh data gateway to my on-prem db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can only access on premise SQL Server databases by building a model & publishing it to powerbi.com using the Power BI Desktop.

If you select "Import" as your connection option, Power BI will store the required data online. You will be able to query on that fixed data and work with it even when your connection to the on premises server is down. You can update your fixed dataset with new data if your connection is properly defined in your gateway.

If you select "DirectQuery" in your Power BI Desktop you will require an active connection to the On premises server for any reporting to work online. On the up side, it'll work on live data and will not store any data online.

When publishing, Power BI Desktop will try to match your connections used in your report to the ones defined in your gateways. If it can find a match, it'll automaticly link those up. It'll give you an informational message to let you know if this step succeeded after publishing. At the same time it'll add a dataset using the same data you used in the reports you just built.

Comment: Thanks, so in order to get the dataset into powerbi.com i always need to run power bi desktop at least once on a pc that has access to the db?

Comment: You currently require Power BI Desktop to create a model of the database you want to use on powerbi.com. Once it's on there you can reuse it as many times as you want. So to answer your question, yes, that would be correct.